# Fixed element problem in mobile browser when keyboard get on screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I don't know how can I describe this that's why I recorded a video. There is fixed yellow text on screen. Fixed text behaviour is normal when keyboard not on screen. When I focus on the screen and the keyboard becomes visible, the fixed item starts to scroll with the page. Is it bug or something? And is there any solution for this?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq60jH4XiJs

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZgKqG

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />
    </head>
      <textarea style="min-height: 50px;"></textarea>
      <div style="height: 1000px; background-color: green">
                    div - height 1000px
      </div>
      <div style="position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; background-color: yellow;">
                    Some Fixed Text
      </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the expected behavior of Safari in iOS when using fixed elements on the page.

Take a look at this article providing a possible solution:
https://medium.com/@im_rahul/safari-and-position-fixed-978122be5f29